# How to see where an error happened in React

Tags: reactjs

I am having errors in my react app but in the console it shows the stack from the compiled code and not the source code. how can I see from where the error comes?
[image]

Comment: it looks like you are using webpack without sourcemap.
try adding devtool: 'eval-source-map' to your webpack.config
more info: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: Hi @benjamin,
I'm not using webpack directly, i use create react app to do it.
ill try google sourcemap for create app thanks

Comment: is this running on production mode ? (NODE_ENV==='production'), I think webpack doesn't build source maps for prod.
In development sometimes it happens, so reloading page or restarting react server may solve.

Comment: @bogdanoff
just checked. no it doesn't